# Error while compiling libhardware_legacy

Tags: android, arm, wifi

Two days ago i read some guides about how to self compile cyanogenmod and i wanted to try on my phone (Galaxy 3 i5800). The phone's CPU architecture is ARMV6 so i downloaded from androidarmv6.github.io the CyanogenMod 10.2 source code and from https://github.com/sdadier/cm10.1_device_samsung_apollo the device folder. At first compilation went pretty good except some "Selected Thumb mode not supported..." errors which i fixed by adding "-marm" CFLAG to involved Android.mk . However now i'm stuck on libhwardware_legacy compilation because i keep getting the error:

```
target thumb C: libhardware_legacy <= hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c
hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c: In function 'update_ctrl_interface':
hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c:473:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c: In function 'wifi_start_supplicant':
hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c:835:4: error: expected identifier before 'unsigned'
hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c:895:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c:912:26: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I searched on Google what that meant and i found lots of thread about this here on StackOverflow and on some Linux forums but none of them referred to Android, Cyanogen or libhardware_legacy. Is it a problem with my system? There is an error in the code ([code here](https://github.com/androidarmv6/android_hardware_libhardware_legacy/blob/cm-10.2/wifi/wifi.c))?

Please give me some suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately undefining LIBC_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES didn't help. What do you mean by searching source/configure?

Comment: I have it, and now i also realized that the problem is there! What do you mean by hard coding for my device? Sorry if i'm asking so many dumb questions but i'm still learning.

Comment: Does your [system_properties.h](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/include/sys/system_properties.h) define `prop_info` like the link or is it different?

Comment: Unfortunately the file is the same, i also checked other versions but they are all alike. Well the problem is appearing in base stuff so it should be exactly like linux.

Comment: I think the `serial` value is versioning the property to see if it got a new value.  You maybe able to remove the versioning completely.  I left an incorrect answer for you to read.  At some point `prop_info` was not *opaque* and had a version; maybe newer version have this, but it seem like a bad interface to do this.

Answer (score 0):

OK! To fix the issue i removed `"const prop_info *pi"` and added this instead:

```
struct prop_info{
unsigned serial;
};
struct prop_info *pi;
```

but i think that if the system compiles it's not going to boot. However i will try to dump the libhardware_legacy from who compile CM10.1 successfully since the code is the same.

UPDATE: I probably found the main issue. The same error came up again and now there are 7 of them and the problem is that they are in the init so i can't workaround. However i noticed that wifi.c and property_service.c have an header in common sys/_system_properties.h probably the main error is there somewhere. Someone has a solution for this?